# Get latest/newest entry of specific partition

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with items of the following structure:

```
[PartitionKey] | [RangeKey] | [Attribute]  
Id               Start        End
```

Now I want to get the latest or newest entry, without knowing the `RangeKey`. I just know the `PartitionKey`. The latest entry has the newest `Start` time.

I can't use the `load` function, because of the missing `RangeKey`. So I have to use a query. But I don't know which one.

Do you know which query is the best for such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort key can be arranged in an order using `ScanIndexForward`.

> If ScanIndexForward is true, DynamoDB returns the results in the order
>   in which they are stored (by sort key value). This is the default
>   behavior. If ScanIndexForward is false, DynamoDB reads the results in
>   reverse order by sort key value, and then returns the results to the
>   client.

**Sample code:-**

The below code retrieves the data by Partition key arranging the sort key in descending order.

```
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Movies");

    QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();

    querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("yearkey = :yearval")
            .withValueMap(
                    new ValueMap().withNumber(":yearval", yearkey))
            .withScanIndexForward(false);

    IteratorSupport<Item, QueryOutcome> iterator = table.query(querySpec).iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Item movieItem = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Movie data ====================>" + movieItem.toJSONPretty());
        moviesJsonList.add(movieItem.toJSON());
    }
```

Comment: And the sort key could be any attribute of the stored item? Or does it need to be the partition key?

Comment: Sort key is nothing but RangeKey. In your case, it is "Start".